# Issues in understanding this integral of $\cos(y)$

Tags: integration

I found myself in the problematic position to be able to follow the next steps of an double integral issue, however pretty much the very first step is not clear to me, hence the final result is meaningless to me.

The official answer:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}x\cos(y) \,dy= x \left[\frac12 \sin(2y)\right]_0^{\pi/4}$$

Would anyone be kind to explain why this is not simply equal to $x \left[\sin(y) \right]$

[Integration problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gldm.png)

Any support appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the equation is not clear, please feel free to check the link below, I struggled a lot to get it right in mathjax format ..

Comment: The upper bound in your question is written as $\frac 4{\pi}$ when it should be reversed. But as it stands, the image you link makes no sense unless the integrand is amended to $\cos 2y$

Comment: thanks a lot, took me hours to figure out how to solve this... now I see, I couldn't  [eth](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/other/mathematik2_biol/Kapitel9)

Answer (score 0):

In the image you linked the integrand should be $x\cdot\cos(2y)$ since $\int\cos2y~dy=\frac12\sin2y$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1290367)

Comment: How does this not answer the question? The OP asked about the first step of the integral in the image he linked, and I wrote that the integrand in the picture is erroneous and what it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\int_0^{ \pi/4} \cos (y) dy= [ \sin (y)]_0^{\pi/4}= \sin ( \pi/4)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$

The official answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\int_0^{4/\pi} cos(y) \,dy= x \left[\frac12 sin(2y)\right] ...$$

is obviously wrong.

The correct answer is $$x\int_0^{4/\pi} cos(y) \,dy= x \sin y |_0^{\pi/4} ...$$